# Add parameters to UILabel initializer

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

This is the code for my custom UILabel:

```
class RoleLabel: UILabel {


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    self.setup()
}

override init(frame:CGRect) {

    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.setup()

}


override  func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setup()

}


func setup(){



    numberOfLines = 1
    font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
    sizeToFit()

    frame = CGRectMake(frame.minX, frame.minY, frame.width + 40, frame.height+5)

    backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    layer.cornerRadius = 5
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    layer.shadowRadius = 2

    drawTextInRect(frame)


    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("X", forState: .Normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(frame.width-20, 1, 20, 23)
    addSubview(btn)



}

let topInset = CGFloat(0), bottomInset = CGFloat(0), leftInset = CGFloat(3), rightInset = CGFloat(0)

override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let insets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}
```

}

However, since the label resizes according to the text, I need to pass the text as an argument to the initializer.

Is there a way to add this kind of custom parameters? 
It doesn't let me add it in `override init(frame:CGRect)`

Answer (score 0):

To override an `init()` method in swift you should use the keyword `convenience`.
As an example you can add the initializer:

```
convenience init(frame:frame, text:String) {

    self.init(frame:frame)
    self.text = text

}
```

Pay attention to the `self.init(frame:frame)` statement which initializes the `UILabel` by calling the default initializer.

Comment: on self.init(frame:frame) it says: "Missing argument for parameter text" @tx2

Comment: did you pasted this initializer as it it on the class that you described?

Comment: I've written it just the way you did, and it says: " "Missing argument for parameter text", on the line : `self.init(frame:frame)`